# Rails Error: Can't understand the message - ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scopes

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4.

I have three models being:

```
User.rb (for authentication and fixed details)
Profile.rb (for user details which can change)
project.rb (for projects that users create)
```

In my projects_controller, I have:

```
def show

    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @creator = User.find(@project.creator_id)
    @creator_profile = @creator.profile

  end
```

The association between user and project is that project belongs to user. In my project table, I have an integer attribute called 'creator_id'. I don't have a separate 'user_id' field.

I have creator, because I want to define users who create projects (so that the project creator links to that user's profile (as opposed to the profile of the current_user who is looking at the project).

In my project model, I have defined a scope and a method as follows:

```
 scope :creator, lambda { where(@creator_profile = user.profile_id)}

 scope :current, lambda { where('project.start_date >= ?', Date.today)}

 def self.all_current_for_creator(creator)
    if creator.profile.present?
       creator.current
    else
      guest_visible
    end
  end
```

Then, in my profile show, I want to show all of the creator's current projects. To do this I have:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <% Project.all_current_for_creator.sort_by(&:created_at) do |project| %>
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="indexdisplay">
                <%= image_tag project.hero_image_url, width: '100%', height: '200px' if project.hero_image.present? %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="indexheading"> <%= link_to project.title, project %> </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="indexsubtext">    
                    <%= truncate(project.description, :ommission => "...", :length => 250) %>
                  </div>              
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>

     <% end %>
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:

```
ArgumentError at /profiles/3
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

I can't understand what this error means. I'm not sure what is looking for an argument and I can't see anything that doesn't have an argument & looks like it should.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: there should be more in the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling:

```
Project.all_current_for_creator
```

Without arguments. You should call it like:

```
Project.all_current_for_creator(@creator)
```

## Update

```
.sort_by(&:created_at) do |project|
```

Should be:

```
.sort_by(&:created_at).each do |project|
```

Because in the first case you are passing two blocks `&:created_at` and `do ...`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I have to wait 5 mins to accept, but it gives me a new error 
both block arg and actual block given

Comment: Thanks! i made a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834960/rails-both-block-arg-and-actual-block-given