# Rails: both block arg and actual block given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lambda, scope

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have this code in my profiles show page, to show all the projects a user has created.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <% Project.all_current_for_creator(@creator).sort_by(&:created_at) do |project| %>
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="indexdisplay">
                <%= image_tag project.hero_image_url, width: '100%', height: '200px' if project.hero_image.present? %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="indexheading"> <%= link_to project.title, project %> </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="indexsubtext">    
                    <%= truncate(project.description, :ommission => "...", :length => 250) %>
                  </div>              
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>

     <% end %>
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:

```
SyntaxError at /profiles/3
both block arg and actual block given
```

Can anyone see what's wrong?

The method 'all_current_for_creator' is defined in my project.rb as:

```
def self.all_current_for_creator(creator)
    if creator.profile.present?
       creator.current.visible
    else
      guest_visible
    end
  end
```

I have defined three scopes in project.rb as:

```
scope :creator, lambda { where(@creator_profile = user.profile_id)}

  scope :current, lambda { where('project.start_date >= ?', Date.today)}
  scope :visible, lambda { joins(:sweep => :disclosure).where('disclosures.allusers' => 'true')
    .joins(:sweep => :finalise).where('finalises.draft' => 'false') }
```

Comment: You would benefit from splitting this view up into partials. Also by loading data in the controller action rather than in the view.

Comment: how do you use the controller action for this?

Comment: Put this on controller: `@projects = Project.all_current_for_creator(@creator).sort_by(&:created_at)`  then in the view use `@projects`

Comment: `<%= render partial: "project", collection: @projects %>`

Comment: I tried this, but it gives an error saying it doesnt recognise my method. I defined 'creator_current' in controller with the action you suggested. Not sure if this is because I'm in profile view trying to call project controller method?

Comment: What is `creator_current`? In the view only reference the instance variables defined in the action. Not methods.

Comment: I made it to name the controller action def creator_current @projects = Project.all_current_for_creator(@creator).sort_by(&:created_at) end

Comment: Ah I see. Don't make a new action. Put the line of code defining `@projects` into the action that renders the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.sort_by(&:created_at) do |project|
```

Should be:

```
.sort_by(&:created_at).each do |project|
```

Because in the first case you are passing two blocks `&:created_at` and `do ...`.